# C - read string from buffer of certain size

Tags: c, string, size, buffer

I have a `char buf[x]`, `int s` and `void* data`.

I want to write a string of size `s` into `data` from `buf`.

How can I accomplish it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `buf` a null-delimited string or is its size defined by `s`? Are you trying to copy just a part of the string? What is `x`? Does the string copied to `data` need to be null-delimited? What have you tried so far?

Comment: note that caf pointed out several mistakes in my answer. I've edited my answer to take his comments into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that

- by “string” you mean a null-terminated string as is normally meant in C;
- you haven't yet allocated memory in `data`;
- you already know that s <= x

First you need to allocate memory in `data`. Don't forget the room for the `0` byte at the end of the string.

```
data = malloc(s+1);
if (data == NULL) {
    ... /*out-of-memory handler*/
}
```

Assuming `malloc` succeeds, you can now copy the bytes.

**EDIT**:

**The best function for the job, as pointed out by caf, is `strncat`.** (It's fully portable, being part of C89.) It appends to the destination string, so arrange for the destination to be an empty string beforehand:

```
*(char*)data = 0;
strncat(data, buf, s);
```

Other inferior possibilities, kept here to serve as examples of related functions:

- If you have `strlcpy` (which is not standard C but is common on modern Unix systems; there are public domain implementations floating around):

  ```
  strlcpy(data, buf, s+1);
  ```
- If you know that there are at least `s` characters in the source string, you can use `memcpy`:

  ```
  memcpy(data, buf, s);
  ```

  ((char*)data)[s+1] = 0;
- Otherwise you can compute the length of the source string first:

  ```
  size_t bytes_to_copy = strlen(buf);
  if (bytes_to_copy > s) bytes_to_copy = s;
  memcpy(data, buf, bytes_to_copy);
  ((char*)data)[s+1] = 0;
  ```
- Or you can use `strncpy`, though it's inefficient if the actual length of the source string is much smaller than `s`:

  ```
  strncpy(data, buf, s);
  ((char*)data)[s+1] = 0;
  ```

Comment: Your `memcpy()` implementations have bugs - they both place the nul terminator incorrectly, and they try to dereference a `void *`, which you can't do.  The first should use `((char *)data)[s] = 0`, and the second should use `((char *)data)[bytes_to_copy] = 0;`.  For the last one, instead of `strncpy()` you can use `strncat()`: `((char *)data)[0] = 0; strncat(data, buf, s);`

Comment: @caf: you're right on both counts. Unfortunately my answer has been accepted, so I've edited it rather than delete it because I don't want to leave a wrong answer too visible. But if you write an strncat answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

If `data` is not allocated:

```
char buf[] = "mybuffer";
void *data = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
strcpy((char*)data,buf);
```

Actually if data is really to be defined you can also do

```
char buf[] = "mybuffer";
void *data= (void*)strdup(buf);
```

Comment: You should `malloc(strlen(buf)+1)`

Comment: Yes, and here `buf` is null-terminated even though [it isn't a string literal](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html). But `strlen(buf)` doesn't include the terminator byte in its count.

Comment: You could use `sizeof buf` instead of `strlen(buf)+1` here since `buf` is an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
memcpy(data, buf, s);
```

This assumes that you have enough space in data (and in buf).

Depending on what you are doing (you don't say, but you do say that you are copying strings), you may want to add a null at the end of your newly copied string if you did not copy a null already in buff, and you are going to use data in a function that expects strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = malloc(s);
strcpy((char*)data,buf);
free(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = MIN((x - 1), s);
char *bp = buf;
char *dp = (char *)data;
while (n--) {
  *bp++ = *dp++;
}
*dp = '\0';
```